# Dealing with altered XML Namespace prefixes in Azure Data Factory data flows

Tags: azure-data-factory

We have ADF pipelines that have successfully been ingesting XML files from blob storage for months now, and then suddenly started failing.

Where things seem to have gone wrong is that the vendor changed the XML format, specifically the namespace prefix from:

```
<d1p1:Header>
```

to the following:

```
<d3:Header>
```

The element names have all stayed the same.

My question is: Is it possible to completely remove the prefixes in ADF? Or ignore them somehow?

So far I haven't been able to find any feature of this kind and when I look at various steps in the data flow it references the full name:

```
{d1p1:Header}
```

So it's not just a case of making a change in a single place and the pipeline is working again.
We also run the risk that if we change the pipeline to accommodate this new prefix, we won't be able to process older files with the old structure unless we duplicate the pipeline before making the changes. This means we're maintaining two pipelines.